# Conditionally render form fields based on user selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The application has several types of properties, such as house, apartment, shop, land, farm, etc..

First, the User selects the type of property in a select field and based on the type of property selected, i need to render the rest of the form with only the specific features of each type of property. I'm using nested attributes with simple_form.

The properties are registered in one table that contains general attributes and a string column with the property type. The other attributes are in separate tables: structural attributes (area, size of the ground, floors, rooms, etc.), address (state, city, district), and specific characteristics (name of condominium, position in the building, etc.)..

I found something similar using the function .change () in jQuery. But I could not make it work in my rails 3 app. Should i use case - when, to render each type form based on the selected value? Should i use partials for each especific form?

How can i, based on the value of the property-type selected in form, render the rest of the fields for each specific type of property?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the horrible English.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally I would render all the forms at once, and hide them with css.  Then using the jQuery .change() function check to see which property type is selected, and use jQuery to unhide the appropriate form sections.  This may be a little more costly to initially load the page, but it will probably be quicker/easier than polling the server to get the appropriate form fields to render after the user selection.

Some pseudo code for this would look like:

Forms:

```
<select id="property_type">
  <option value='type_1'>Type 1</option>
  <option value='type_2'>Type 2</option>
</select>

<div id='type_1' class='type_forms'>
  <form></form>
</div>

<div id='type_2' class='type_forms'>
  <form></form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('select#property_type').bind('change', function() {
  $('.type_forms').hide();
  $('.type_forms input').attr('disabled', true);
  var selection = $(this).val();
  $('#' + selection).show();
  $('#' + selection + ' input').attr('disabled', false);
}).change();
```

This can definitely be approved upon, but hopefully it helps to illustrate the idea.

If you need to poll the server you could though using an ajax call within the .change() function to inform a controller action of the user select, and then have it render an appropriate partial to display in the ajax callback.

Comment: Hmm, good.
BUt in this case, some properties types have similar fields, others don't, example: some have "floors", others have "name", etc. 
Then i can't show like a form section because some fields may not be in that type..
I was thinking of make one partial per type, with the apropriate fields, and then use jquery to show tha div that will render the right partial.. but how do i do that? Can i use the select field value as a variable name, to be passed to the render => comand?

Comment: In order to render a partial depending on the type you would need to make an ajax request to a controller action that does the render based on the selection.  Thats bad idea in my opinion as it's more effective to render ALL of the partials at once when the form is initially rendered.  Wrap each set of appropriate fields in a div or something that you can easily just hide & disable all of its form fields when it's not selected.  Then when a selection is made you just show & enable appropriate fields.  It doesnt matter that some are not the right ones for certain types if you disable & hide.

Comment: ok, so its better to have a big form page (there are 24 property-types, with -+ 20 fields each) with a complete form per type in each div (like 400 fields), than making a controller request? thats it? Or you are talking about one div per field, and make an conditional in jquery to render just the apropriate ones? in that case would be a big conditional! (24 types) am i wrong? Thanks for the patience, im still learning the best pratices and your help has been very important!

Comment: Yeah I would do a complete form for each type with each wrapped in a div with an ID or Class identifier for each type. So you could hide & disable them all to start.  Once the user selects a type you could have the jQuery then show & enable the appropriate div & form by using the selection value if you have identified each div with the selection values for the types. I'll try adding some example code to my answer.

Comment: Thanks man!!! it works like a charm!! just one more question about the code you paste: why the attr ('disabled') method?

Comment: Well the attr disable is to ensure the inputs are disabled so they dont get submitted to the server.  This was code I extracted from a similar page I had to your needs.  It would actually only be necessary if you only had a single form with just the inputs being hidden for each type rather than a form for each type.  However still disabling all of the fields that are not shown could be a good safety precaution if someone were to use xss to maliciously submit your hidden forms with javascript.

Comment: Great, i was thinking about something similar,to send just the data in the selected form, but you did it  already!! thanks again!